# MySQL error with insert function in Nodejs (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Im trying to use insert function and Im getting all the time an error :( Im trying to insert into user table a name of the user

My function:

```
 function insert(tableName, toField, value){
    connection.connect();
    var queryString = "insert into "+tableName+" ("+toField+") 
    select "+connection.escape(value)+"";    

    connection.query(queryString, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });     
}
```

and in the main code:

```
var name ="Anna";
Helpers.insert('user', 'name', name);
```

Everytime I get an error:

```
Uncaught exception: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near ''user' ('name') select 'Anna'' at line 1
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near ''user' ('name') select 'Anna'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it :) Thank for your help!!

```
 function insert(tableName, toField, value){
    connection.connect();
    var queryString = "INSERT INTO  "+tableName+" ("+toField+") VALUES ("+connection.escape(value)+")";    

    connection.query(queryString, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Values() which is missing,

```
var queryString = "insert into "
    +connection.escape(tableName)+" ("+connection.escape(toField)+")
    Values (" + connection.escape(value)+")";
```

Comment: The same ;( Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' ('name')values 'Anna'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
    var queryString = 
        "INSERT INTO " + connection.escapeId(tableName)
```

You could use `connection.escapeId` to escape an identifier (as opposed to a value).

Comment: still the same ;( Uncaught exception: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Anna`' at line 1

Comment: @AnnaK could you do `var query = connection.query(...)` and then `console.log(query.sql)`?

Comment: insert into `user` (`name`) values `Anna`
That I get from console.log(queryString). Is it strange. Isn't? Because it looks ok